# Haskell default superclass instances

Tags: haskell, typeclass, boilerplate

I want to take some of the boilerplate out of Num declarations for a few custom classes (call them Monomial and Polynomial). Instead of writing

```
instance Num (Monomial) where
    f - g = f + (negate g)
    abs _ = undefined
```

Is there a way to get around this? I came across [default superclass instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DefaultSuperclassInstances) and something called "[the strathclyde haskell enhancement](http://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/~conor/pub/she/superclass.html)" which if implemented might let me write something like,

```
class SimpleNum a => Num a where
    (+) :: a -> a -> a -- standard ring stuff
    (*) :: a -> a -> a
    one :: a
    zero :: a
    instance Num (SimpleNum a) where
        f - g = f + (negate g)
        abs _ = undefined
```

What's the usual / simple way of dealing with this?

Comment: Maybe this is partially an issue of the design of Num not being very good, i.e. it should be AbelianGroup => Ring => Num ...

Comment: that's part of it, but then we couldn't have defaults for methods of the less-specific typeclasses in terms of members of the more-specific ones, so that would suck too really :-(. Though at least then our code wouldn't have to have all these gratuitous bottoms...

Comment: SHE *is* implemented.  I don't know if this feature is, but SHE is a real preprocessor that you can use.

Comment: Are you aware of the Numeric Prelude, http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Prelude ?  It provides a more sensible Num at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual ways of dealing this is to do at least one or more of the following:

1. Grumble a lot.
2. Write helper functions like this:

```
simpleMinus f g = f + (negate g)
```

1. Use tools like [Template Haskell](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell) and [Derive](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/derive).
2. Attempt to implement extensions like the one you mention. (This unfortunately not as easy as you might think.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably just write it this time since I only have a few functions, but good to know about Template Haskell and Derive.